# PPA for Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: ppa, eclipse

Is there a PPA for Eclipse Juno 4.2? If not, would it be too difficult to create one, perhaps based on the official packaging?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: This is the official eclipse ppa https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/ppa .  If I remember correctly there are licensing issues around which parts of eclipse are freely redistributable.

Part 1: No.  Juno is not in that PPA.
Part 2: I've never tried rolling up eclipse.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing: Well, the PPA you mentioned is rather dated. A pity.

Comment: Sorry.  It does seem dated, but it is the official one.

Comment: The Eclipse Team and Ubuntu needs to take more seriously the collaboration. The official PPA shows packages from 3.5 and the new Ubuntu releases 13.04 or even 13.10 are not getting any serious update with 3.8. Please, someone with influence in ubuntu or Eclipse speak about it and try to improve the situation. Leaving a IDE without updates for ubuntu means that a lot developers will switch losing percent market for Eclipse or Ubuntu. Put easy and friendly for developers, then the users will come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [official Eclipse PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/ppa).

If I remember correctly there are licensing issues around which parts of Eclipse are freely redistributable.

1. No, Juno is not in that PPA.
2. I've never tried rolling up Eclipse.

Comment: This PPA is very outdated.

Comment: @RolandiXor - I do not disagree.  Maybe the ppa maintainers need a new member.  Any volunteers?